# how to make mutiple search in table for jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

i want my code in jsfiddle to be multiple search. here's my code:
when i search 55 . it's working. but what if i search "55 553" is it possible to highlight two rows?

```
$('#search').keyup(function(){
    var needle = $(this).val();
    $('.highlight').removeClass('highlight');
    $('td.hidden:contains("' + needle + '")')
        .filter(function(){
            return $(this).text() == needle;
        })
        .closest('tr')
        .addClass('highlight');
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/AsSDQ/1/

instead of highlighting the rows, i want to hide table rows that is not part of the search

Comment: "i want my code in jsfiddle"? What is the problem? What is the question?

Comment: Please give your jsfiddle url and explain your problem

Comment: Refer this link you will get an idea- http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/D6nzC/

Comment: @Suhas - http://jsfiddle.net/D6nzC/16/ try searching 3, it will not work and will post 3 and 33

Comment: Hi @user2739179 do you want to see or use any demo plugin and find out the solution ? see here http://jquery-plugins.net/jquery-filter-table-plugin

Comment: @Gadde - try to type 1. all of the values that have 1 highlights.
i need is that when i type 1, the exact number 1 is highlighted

Comment: @user2739179 see this http://jsfiddle.net/FLhMj/1/

Comment: @user2739179 just check out my answer and http://jsfiddle.net/AsSDQ/28/, I guess thats what you want. remember to mark it as an answer if thats what you want. cheers!

Answer (score 1):

```
   $('#search').keyup(
function () {
    var needles = $(this).val().split(" ");
   $("tr").hide();
        $('.highlight').removeClass('highlight');

    for (i = 0; i < needles.length; i++) {
        $('td.hidden:contains("' + needles[i] + '")')
        .filter(
            function () {
                return $(this).text() == needles[i];
            })
        .closest('tr')
        .addClass('highlight');
    }
    $('.highlight').show();
    if($(this).val()=="")
     {
        $("tr").show()
     }
});
```

this code will work..

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/anoopjoshy9895/cVESe/)

Answer (score 1):

This should be the answer you are looking for

[JS Fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/AsSDQ/28/) thats the answer, I am not really sure how to post the answer here and I tried it doesn't really work out.

```
$('#search').keyup(
    function(){
       var needle = $(this).val();
       var splitNeedle = needle.split(" ");
       $('.test').html(splitNeedle.length)
       $('.highlight').removeClass('highlight');
       for(var i=0;i<splitNeedle.length;i++){
       $('td.hidden:contains("' + splitNeedle[i] + '")')
            .filter(
                function(){
                    return $(this).text() == splitNeedle[i];
                })
            .closest('tr')
            .addClass('highlight');
        }
});
```